# Calculate a triple integral which is bounded by planes

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

> Calculate:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\iiint\limits_Gf(x;y;z)dxdydz,\ \text{where}\\
> &G\ \text{is bounded by the planes}\ y=-x,\ z=x,\ z=y,\ z=1,\ \text{and}\\
> &f(x;y;z)=x^2-z^2
> \end{aligned}
> $$

I've been struggling to plot $G$, and, unfortunately, it didn't help much since I couldn't get much out of it. So, I thought that there might be some sort of analytical solution to this problem. I understand that the most difficult part is to go to the iterated integral, but I don't really know how to do that.
So, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: To say that $G$ is bounded by some planes doesn't define what is $G$. I think that you want to set $G$ as the maximal convex set contained by these planes, right?

Comment: Well, yes. I meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the $xy$-plane, the triple integral is over the two shaded regions, for which the $z$-integral is bounded by $z=x$ and $z=1$ in the purple region and by $z=y$ and $z=1$ in the blue region.

Thus, the integral can be set up as

$$I = \int_0^1dx\int_{-x}^{x}dy\int_x^1(x^2-z^2)dz+\int_0^1dy\int_{-y}^{y}dx\int_y^1(x^2-z^2)dz$$

which can then be integrated analytically.

Comment: Thank you very much! But could you please explain how you got the limits for $z$?In the first case, for example?

Comment: @Bonrey - In the first case, the $z$-direction is capped by $z=1$ from above and its Lowe bound is provided by the plane $z=x$, hence the limits being $(x, 1)$.